# Button click not responding when it opens into IE Driver using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have selenium webdriver tests in which i have to perform actions on buttons elements and other element using IE Driver, I am observing sometimes on button click application is responding and **sometimes not.** 
I am seeing one more strange behavior after stopping execution when i tried to perform actions manually on same instance of browser using mouse, application does not respond, i have to press enter button then only application responds.

Application web app is from Guidewire product and onshield. However i am not seeing any issue with chrome.

Answer (score -1):

I've had this issue as well. Im using Java so instead of using driver.findElement(By.......).click() I was calling JavaScript on the element to perform my actions. This worked alot better in IE for my tests than using the driver.

Comment: Are you seeing same behavior what i am observing on IEdriver "I am seeing one more strange behavior after stopping execution when i tried to perform actions manually on same instance of browser using mouse, application does not respond, i have to press enter button then only application responds."